# Where to download old version 2.6.x of Saiku

Tags: saiku

I have downloaded Saiku CE from http://community.meteorite.bi/.
Information in REAME file:

### " SAIKU README

Saiku Suite V2.1 GA
OSGI Ltd
...
…

### Important known problems

There is an issue with XML/A connections with Mondrian XML/A instances. This issue is caused by mondrian and not saiku and will be fixed for the 2.0 stable release
…
"

Using and old Mondrian Schema file, I met the same issue as published  on https://groups.google.com/a/saiku.meteorite.bi/d/msg/user/exjt7rVg5Oo/SQeEgglIicsJ .

The easiest way is to download Saiku with version 2.*.*.

Where to download old versions?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the standalone version from here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Vsgah5rueFVFF5ZklXRUlQLVk/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-Zb9CdSf7mTksiSBls9Vf8Q

Note: Link updated according to new security rules on drive.